# Getting SIM card data via .Net

Tags: c#, .net, sim-card

I need to access a SIM card and get the SIM card Serial No, Phone No. and carrier from SIM card at5tached to a PC via a USB/SIM adapter.

.Net platform, C# prefered.

Any ideas?

BP...

Comment: did you try asking the vendor?

Comment: I am not necessarily talking about a specific vendor. Is this fuctionality vendor specific? I thought that once the SIM card is recognized by the system, a specific API ( via some dll ) would provide this fuctionality.

Comment: did you try asking the vendor?

Comment: What kind of device do you use to plug the SIM to USB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

probably this [code](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/) library should help

or this

http://www.sharpdevelop.net/OpenSource/SharpUSBLib/default.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this solves your problem, but maybe you will take a look at this:
[gsmcomm library](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)

Answer (score 0):

This [SIM card SDK](http://sim-reader.com/sim-card-sdk) does exactly what you need. It is compatible with any card type you can think of, and it includes a .NET wrapper. There's sample app in C# that shows how the whole thing works.

I am one of the developers, specifically, the guy who reads the standards and implements support for different file types. We continuously update it to add compatibility with new cards that are used by carriers in various parts of the world.